# Creating a file on my website using VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I have searched but couldn't get any real solution to creating a file on my website by uploading the file from the local system using VB.net

This is my code so far

```
        Dim rdr As New FileStream(ReSaveFile, FileMode.Open)
        Dim req As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("http://www.timemedian.com/display.txt"), HttpWebRequest)
        req.Method = "POST"
        ' you might use "POST"
        req.ContentLength = rdr.Length
        req.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = True

        Dim reqStream As Stream = req.GetRequestStream()

        Dim inData As Byte() = New Byte(rdr.Length - 1) {}

        ' Get data from upload file to inData 
        Dim bytesRead As Integer = rdr.Read(inData, 0, rdr.Length)

        ' put data into request stream
        reqStream.Write(inData, 0, rdr.Length)

        rdr.Close()
        req.GetResponse()

        ' after uploading close stream 
        reqStream.Close()
```

but I cant possible see the error. Please help

Comment: I am guessing you have a client that sends a file to your website. The code above is that client's code right?

Now does what does your server do when it get's the request? The obvious question is, Does it save the file?

Comment: Sorry to have replied late. It does not create not save the file to my website

Comment: You can't just "write a textfile" to your web server. You have to *upload* it, and the server has to accept the uploaded file and store it somewhere. (If you could just write files at will on the web server, your web server wouldn't be yours for long.)

Comment: Please can you help me with an example? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uploaded the file using ftp protocol like this

```
 Try
                       Dim mReq1 As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.websitename.com//" & SetID & ".pvx"), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)

                        mReq1.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password")
                        mReq1.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

                        Dim MFile1() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(ReSaveFile)

                        Dim mStream1 As System.IO.Stream = mReq1.GetRequestStream()
                        mStream1.Write(MFile1, 0, MFile1.Length)

                        mStream1.Close()
                        mStream1.Dispose()
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        MsgBox("Your file was not fully posted to the remote server. PVX Mail may not function properly")
                        Exit Sub
                    End Try
```